# Efficiently create random sample from expand.grid output without using expand.grid

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, combinatorics

Let's suppose I have 3 vectors (just as an example). Now I want to obtain a random sample over all possible combinations of those 3. Usually, I'd do this:

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 10:12
z <- 15:18

N <- length(x) * length(y) * length(z) # Length of the resulting grid
idx <- sample(1:N, 10, replace = FALSE)
my_grid <- expand.grid(x, y, z)
result <- my_grid[idx, ]
```

That's fine for small vectors. But if those vectors grow in size, `my_grid` will get very big very fast. So the question is, how to create the `result` by only using `idx` and the three vectors?

Comment: sample a value in x, a value in y, and a value in z?

Comment: I thought about that, but I think it has drawbacks. For example, how do I decide how many observations to sample from each vector?  Furthermore, I'd possibly need to sample a little more than needed to ensure I end up with enough rows in the `result`.

Comment: Ah, you sample without replacement?

Comment: Yes. It is the default behavior of the sample function. I added the argument to my question to be a bit more explicit about this.

Comment: Hello BerriJ. I wrote a [blog post](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/CantorExpansionRevisited.html) based on this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```r
X <- list(x, y, z)
X.len <- sapply(X, length)

# modify '%%' to return values 1..n instead of 0..(n-1)
mod2 <- function(x, y) (x-1) %% y + 1

result <- sapply(seq_along(X), function(i) 
  X[[i]][mod2(ceiling(idx / prod(X.len[seq_len(i-1)])),  
              X.len[i])]
)
```

Basically, the columns of the output of `expand.grid` for each vector are formed by blocks of values and the length of each block is a product of the lengths of the "preceding" vectors. So you just divide the index by this product and than take modulo from this number to find which value would be on that position.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the `expand.grid`, you can use a [Cantor expansion](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/Greedy.html) of the integers. This is a generalization of the binary expansion. See the above link for details. In short, each integer in `1:(n1*n2*n3)` has a Cantor expansion `(x1, x2, x3)` with `x1` in `1:n1`, `x2` in `1:n2`, `x3` in `1:n3`. The binary expansion is the case `n1 = n2 = n3 = 2`.

Here is the code for your example:

```r
intToCantor <- function(n, sizes) {
  l <- c(1, cumprod(sizes))
  epsilon <- numeric(length(sizes))
  while(n>0){
    k <- which.min(l<=n)
    e <- floor(n / l[k-1])
    epsilon[k-1] <- e
    n <- n - e*l[k-1]
  }
  epsilon
}

CantorToInt <- function(epsilon, sizes) {
  sum(epsilon * c(1, cumprod(sizes[1:(length(epsilon)-1)])))
}

x <- 1:3
y <- 10:12
z <- 15:18

sizes <- c(length(x), length(y), length(z))
N <- prod(sizes)
n <- 10
idx <- sample(1:N, n, replace = FALSE)

result <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = n, ncol = length(sizes))
for(i in 1:n) {
  indices <- 1 + intToCantor(idx[i] - 1, sizes = sizes)
  result[i, ] <- c(x[indices[1]], y[indices[2]], z[indices[3]])
}
```

The above link provides a **Rcpp** function to replace `intToCantor`.

---

## EDIT

@Robert Hacken's answer provides a more efficient way. In fact, his answer uses a hidden Cantor expansion, faster than mine:

```r
mod2 <- function(x, y) {
  (x-1) %% y
}
Cantor_Hacken <- function(n, sizes) {
  p <- cumprod(c(1, head(sizes, -1)))
  mod2(ceiling((n + 1) / p), sizes)
}
```

---

## EDIT

The **Rcpp** function is faster:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector CantorRcpp(int n, std::vector<int> sizes) {
  IntegerVector epsilon(sizes.size(), 1);
  std::vector<int>::iterator it = sizes.begin();
  it = sizes.insert(it, 1);
  int G[sizes.size()];
  std::partial_sum(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(), G, std::multiplies<int>());
  n--;
  int k;
  while(n > 0) {
    k = 1;
    while(G[k] <= n) {
      k += 1;
    }
    int d = G[k-1];
    epsilon(k-1) = 1 + n / d;
    n = n % d;
  }
  return epsilon;
}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)

CantorExpansion <- function(n, sizes) {
  p <- cumprod(c(1L, head(sizes, -1L)))
  1L + ((ceiling(n / p) - 1L) %% sizes)
}

sizes <- 2L:9L
Robert <- function() {
  L <- vector("list", length = prod(sizes))
  for(n in seq_len(prod(sizes))) {
    L[[n]] <- CantorExpansion(n, sizes)
  }
}
Rcpp <- function() {
  L <- vector("list", length = prod(sizes))
  for(n in seq_len(prod(sizes))) {
    L[[n]] <- CantorRcpp(n, sizes)
  }
}
microbenchmark(
  Robert = Robert(),
  Rcpp = Rcpp(),
  times = 10L
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#  Robert 1658.3666 1690.2473 1743.9026 1728.0874 1765.9536 1910.122    10   b
#    Rcpp  693.8287  764.4371  841.9733  801.9504  947.8049 1050.848    10  a 
*/
```

One can improve both functions because the cumulative product can be calculated only once.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. However, it does not produce the desired output. The `result` object differs from mine. Therefore I accepted Roberts's answer which is also faster.

Comment: @BerriJ Strange, I get exactly the same result. I suspect Robert's answer hides another way to do the Cantor expansion. I didn't understand yet.

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right, they both produce the same result. Stupid, I just copied your code and didn't realize that `idx` will be different from run to run. So thank you again, this whole cantor expansion was new to me and its very interesting.

Comment: @BerriJ Please see my edit. I was right: Robert's answer also uses the Cantor expansion.

Comment: @BerriJ The **Rcpp** function is faster, take a look at my edit. But I didn't try the **Rcpp** version of Robert's function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random subset without generating a full table of all combinations, i.e., `expand.grid`, you can try, for example

```
f <- function(lst, n, replace = FALSE) {
    res <- list()
    if (replace) {
        res <- replicate(n, sapply(lst, sample, 1), simplify = FALSE)
    } else {
        repeat {
            if (length(res) == n) break
            v <- list(sapply(lst, sample, 1))
            if (!v %in% res) {
                res <- append(res, v)
            }
        }
    }
    as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, res))
}
```

where the argument `replace = FALSE` indicates no replacement during sampling.

## Output Example

Given `lst <- list(x, y , z)`:

- sampling ***with*** replacement

```
> f(lst, 10, TRUE)
   V1 V2 V3
1   2 10 17
2   1 10 17
3   3 10 18
4   2 12 18
5   1 10 17
6   3 10 17
7   3 11 17
8   2 12 17
9   2 12 18
10  2 12 15
```

- sampling ***without*** replacement

```
> f(lst, 10, FALSE)
   V1 V2 V3
1   2 12 17
2   1 12 17
3   2 12 15
4   3 12 17
5   2 11 15
6   3 12 18
7   1 10 15
8   3 10 17
9   1 11 17
10  3 12 16
```